# What is this sequence trying to describe?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A Chinese friend of mine asked me to have a look at this piece of mathematics.

I see a quadratic form and some kind of a sequence but I can't make out what is being done here.

Does anyone recognize this?

If I could just be directed to an English version that would be great.

[image]

Comment: This looks like Vieta's formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: I've never studied or heard of Vieta's formulas but from the link it looks like that's exactly it. Time to learn Vieta's formulas. Thanks